# My yticks Overlap in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-3.4

I'm working on a graphic with matplotlib in Python 3.4 that represents:

x = (months)
y = (12 values)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import calendar

N = 12
mult = 12500
x = np.arange(N)
y = mult *np.random.randn(12)

plt.plot(x, y, 'r')
plt.xticks(x, calendar.month_name[1:13], rotation=20 )
plt.yticks(y, y)
plt.grid('on')
plt.margins(0.05)
plt.show()
```

Tha labels of the yticks are the values in y, but when some values are very similar the ylabels overlap.

Example:

[image: example image]

I've tried linespacing property, but it just works with each label it doesnt affect to the set.

How do I give some spacing to the ylabels or avoid that overlapping?

Comment: As a person who reads a lot of graphs, I'd suggest that labeling the y-axis this way is kind of disorienting. I'd label the y-axis with regular intervals, and label the individual *points* with their y-coords. Like [this, for example](http://i.imgur.com/QWf6WQq.png).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in a comment by @jme: "As a person who reads a lot of graphs, I'd suggest that labeling the y-axis this way is kind of disorienting. I'd label the y-axis with regular intervals, and label the individual points with their y-coords. Like this, for example:
[image]

Comment: The jme's comment for me was a good and enough answer. How am I supposed to close the question if he commented it instead of giving an answer? I answered my own question to then accept it and close it.

Comment: @GerardEnjuanes: I think the best way to close a question that was answered in a comment is to either ask the commenter to post an answer, or simply write on yourself, stating something along the lines of "As pointed out in a comment by jme, …" and the select your own answer as the accepted one.